# C# console application timer issue

Tags: c#, .net, timer

I have a console applciation which is invoked by a Windows Service. This console application creates instances of System.Timers.Timer based on certain App.config file entries (I have created a custom App.config section and the number of timer instances will be same as that of the elements in this section). The console application is expected not to close -  if it closes for some reason, the windows service will invoke it again.

To make the console application live for ever, I have an infinite loop written as the last statement of the console application.  while (1 == 1) { }.

The issue is, I see that the console application terminates every 5 minutes. I don't understand why is this happening.

If there are any better approaches, please suggest.

### Code

static void Main(string[] args)
        {

```
        Boolean _isNotRunning;
        using (Mutex _mutex = new Mutex(true, _mutexID, out _isNotRunning))
        {
            if (_isNotRunning)
            {
                new ProcessScheduler().InitializeTimers();                             
                while (1 == 1) { }                                                         
            }
            else
            {  
                return;
            }
        }
```

public class ProcessScheduler
    {

```
public void InitializeTimers()
    {
        XYZConfigSection.XYZAppSection section =  (XYZConfigSection.XYZAppSection)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("XYZApp");        
        if (section != null)
        {
            XYZComponentTimer XYZComponentTimer = null;
            for (int intCount = 0; intCount < section.XYZComponents.Count; intCount++)
            {
                XYZComponentTimer = new XYZComponentTimer();
                XYZComponentTimer.ComponentId = section.XYZComponents[intCount].ComponentId;
                XYZComponentTimer.Interval = int.Parse(section.XYZComponents[intCount].Interval);
                XYZComponentTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(XYZComponentTimer_Elapsed);
                XYZComponentTimer.Enabled = true;                    
            }
        }
    }
```

}

```
public class XYZComponentTimer:Timer
{        
    public string ComponentId { get; set; }
}
```

**Update:**

As mentioned in the code, the timer interval for each instance is set based on the config file values for corresponding element. Right now, there are two sections in the config file: one has an interval of 15 seconds, and another one 10 seconds.

Answer (score 3):

Let me guess: The timer interval is 5min and the timer crashes causing the process to exit.

Why don't you log any crashes or attach a debugger?

Comment: I don't see the application crashing when I run it on my development machine with a debugger attached. The ap will run for ever with no issues. I see this only when I put it on a remote computer.

Comment: Put try-catch everywhere and log exceptions to a file (File.AppendAllText). You already know there is a bug. You need to start doing something to find it. Staring at the code is ineffective.

Answer (score 1):

Handle the [AppDomain.UnhandledException event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception.aspx) and log the exception.

Answer (score 0):

Mutex was getting instantiated every 5 minutes for some weird reason, and was setting _isNotRunning to true. That was the issue.